# How to default nemo to forget LUKS password?

Tags: encryption, linux-mint, luks, nemo

I just finished encrypting all my drives with LUKS.  Right now I boot Mint 20.1 off an ssd and have a 6TB hdd.  Both drives are now encrypted with LUKS.  In the nemo file browser when I click on my 6TB drive it prompts me for the password along with asking if it should "Forget password immediately", "Remember password until you logout", or "Remember forever".  The default is remember until you log out.

Does anyone know how to change this default?  I would like it to forget immediately always.

I know I can check that box every time, but that is slightly annoying and I forget sometimes.  I would like it to re-prompt me every time I un-mount the drive and have this be the default behavior.

Also if I do have it remember my password until I logout where does it store it?

Answer (score 2):

The change to "Remember password until you logout" becoming the default was done
in 2010 in response to bug-report
[Bug 587909 - Default setting for remembering password should be remember until logout](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587909).
Unfortunately, this was implemented as
[hard coded](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/commit/3094265abbfd3b70b39bb1dbd9625a81faf0fbca).

So there exists no user-setting for changing this default.

By default, passwords are stored in the
[GNOME keyring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring)
for all applications that support it.
You may have available the
[Seahorse](http://packages.ubuntu.com/seahorse)
GUI program or the
[secret-tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/secret-tool.1.html)
command line utility to view and modify the contents of the keyring.

For more information see the post
[How does Nautilus store passwords on Ubuntu?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108242/how-does-nautilus-store-passwords-on-ubuntu)

Comment: So right now by default nemo is storing the password with the gnome keyring daemon?  So does this mean that other programs running as my user can query the password?

Comment: Yes, they can do so.

Comment: My god this is irresponsible.